# populating a string array dynamically from a column of phrases in an excel sheet

Tags: arrays, string, excel, vba

I have 2 sheets.  I am using a user-defined function in sheet 1, in which I want to use an array to compare some strings.  The array is comprised of the contents of a column of cells in the second sheet (which is named "phrases.").

So (looking at it another way) in "phrases" I have 100 strings typed into column P, cells 3 to 102.  And I want to put all of them into an array that i can use later.

Now, let me complicate it a little - my intent is that users of the spreadsheet will be able to add new content to column P, so that it may eventually be 500 cells or more.  So I really want to populate that array dynamically.

Here's where i am - and it doesn't seem to be working:

```
Dim newarray() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim counter As Long
counter = 0
For i = 0 To 5000
    If Worksheets("phrases").Cells(i + 3, 16).Value <> 0 Then
    newarray(counter) = Worksheets("phrases").Range(i + 3, 16).Value
    counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next
```

Where am i going wrong?

Please note - I've tried this without `.Value` - didn't seem to work.
I've tried this with `.Text` instead of `.Value` - didn't seem to work.
I've tried `CStr(Worksheets("phrases").Range(i + 3, 16).Value)` and several variations - and it didn't seem to work.

I expect there is something simple I am missing here - but i have no idea what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim newarray() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lr AS Long
Dim counter As Long
lr = ActiveSheet.Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
counter = 0
For i = 1 To lr
    If Worksheets("phrases").Range("P" & i).value <> 0 Then
        Redim Preserve newarray(counter)
        newarray(counter) = Worksheets("phrases").Range("P" & i).value
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would help solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks - this worked - but i'm not sure why.  I changed "ActiveSheet." to "Worksheets("phrases")." because phrases was not the active sheet - presume that was correct (it worked).
Your clearly handled the dynamic column size with "ActiveSheet.Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row" - but I have no idea how you formed that object reference.
Clearly I need to learn about ReDim.
Finally - it looks like my "counter variable is moot here (except perhaps in the case of having some empty cells in the column.
Nonetheless, Thanks much

Comment: Ken, referring to active sheet means just whichever sheet is selected at the time the macro will run on. If you want it to run on a specific sheet yes you would refer to it as worksheets("name") or you could just refer to it by index number worksheets(1), worksheets(2), ect. where 1 is the first worksheet in the workbook 2 is the second and so on.

Answer (score 0):

First construct a **comma-separated string**.  Then convert the string into an **array** using the *Split()* function.

Comment: Thanks.  will try that later (the answer above worked) - but my algorithm has several arrays in it - and i, will try to form one of the other ones that way as a learning exercise

Answer (score 0):

You can make the array directly from the cells without having to loop at all using a single line of code, this will also capture anything that the user adds to the bottom of column P by using the `Resize()` method:

```
Sub SO()

stringArray = [P3:P102].Resize(Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 2, 1)

'// Print each value in the array
For Each x In stringArray
    Debug.Print CStr(x)
Next x

End Sub
```